# Sqflite Database exception type in flutter

Tags: sqlite, exception, flutter, sqflite

I am using package Sqflite for database management in flutter, I want to discriminate database exception, i.e. I want to know what went wrong during INSERT query, whether it was missing table or a mismatch in column name or trying to insert duplicate value in a column with UNIQUE constraint.
In following code I am able to catch exceptions but I am unable to discriminate them.

```
    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
    try {
      id = await helper.insertMeter(dataMap);
      print('inserted row: $id');
    } catch (ex) {
      // Here I want to know what caused exception.
      print('Failed to insert: ' + ex.toString());
    }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the native report we get is not always consistent between iOS and Android. There are some helpers you can use if you catch explicitely a [DatabaseException](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseException-class.html) such as isUniqueConstraintError, isNoSuchTableError. It is based on parsing the exception text thrown for a few example tested. Some could be added assuming we can parse a relevant error but it cannot be more than what we can extract from the string you currently print.